# How to pass multiple values to drilldown report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I m using sql 2008. I have one matrix on the report. Data will be as follow

```
                Maths   English  Science   
Gender            5        3        4
 Male             1        2        2
 Female           4        1        2
```

Count shows the number of students passed in respective subjects.Data is grouped by gender When user click on count it will be redirect to sub report. Now i want to pass Students Ids to sub report to show that students only. I have tried Join, Split but those functions can be used with parameters only. Not with Fields. Basically i want to pass string of comma separated students ids to sub report.

I have searched on Google but not finding any solution. So awaiting for solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this recently by setting a click action in a tablix control. Essentially, I went to the *Text Box Properties* I went to *Action* and then set the action as *Go to URL*. I've then put an expression in for the following (which you can modify to your needs depending on the destination report name and parameters):

```
=IIf(
    Parameters!p_hide_links.Value="y", 
    Nothing, 
    "javascript: void( window.open('http://' + window.location.host + '/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Property+Management/" & replace(Parameters!i_this_report.Value, " ", "+") & 
    "&p_from_date=" & Parameters!p_from_date.Value &
    "&p_to_date=" & Parameters!p_to_date.Value &
    "&p_lease_exec=" & Fields!submitted_by.Value &
    "&p_building_state=" & Parameters!p_building_state.Value &
    "&p_division_id=" & Parameters!p_division_id.Value &
    "&p_building_id=" & Parameters!p_building_id.Value &
    "&p_view_type=d" &
    "') );"
)
```

Comment: Note: If you're unsure how to adapt this please let me know your destination report name and parameters and I'll happily update the expression for you

Comment: Actually male and female row comes under 'Gender_Name' group. So if i pass Fields!StudentId.Value in url then it gives only one student id instead of all students ids comes in count. So i think your solution will not work for me.

Comment: @Michael can you please help with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917941/how-to-exclude-column-from-a-report

Answer (score 0):

This might be the answer you are looking for:

Right Click on any text box select TextBox Properties and do as in below jpg.

[image]

Now select the detail report from the drop down [create new if its not there]

pass the parameters whichever you wanted to and this will be like input parameter to this sub report and using any details dataset you can show on the report view.

Let me know if you face any problems in that.

Comment: I know how to pass parameter in sub-report. But in my case i have applied group on row. And if user click on 3 then all 3 student IDs should be passed to sub-report. Hope u understand my point.

Comment: OK...So you can twist the parameters instead of id's you can send the SUBJECT(ENGLISH) and GENDER and retrive the students details from the database.You can pass anything to get the student data satisfying the simillar criterion.