# Exporting a SSRS Report with Jump to report in excel?

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am working in SSRS to generate drill down reports. There is a report which uses the jump to report as a navigation parameter. The report works perfectly on reporting server but when exported to excel the links do not work.

I guess when the ssrs report is exported to excel file it is exported with the hyperlinks which points to the reporting server.

What I am trying to do is get the jump to report navigation functionality between the reports.

for example suppose I have a report named **Users** which list some users and when the name of the user is clicked the report jumps to the another report **(User_details)** with additional information. This works fine with the reporting server.
But when I export both the reports into excel sheets. The same navigation behavior is not there and I end up with the following message.

```
Unable to open http://reortserver/?%2FdrilldownReport2&Region=WW&rs%3AParameterLanguage=. Cannot locate the Internet server or proxy server.
```

Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post example of link which was generated in your Excel? And add more information about how it's not working.

Comment: @RomanBadiornyi just did so....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url for report preview buildings as:

```
http://[instance_name]/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx/[ReportPath]
```

Check by hand if this link to your drill down report is available, maybe you are missing some permissions? Looking at your situation, everything should work fine.

**UPDATED:**
If you want to add navigation in excel (without report server) - you can change drill down link to return excel file of drill down report.
You can add to your drill down report parameters - additional conditional parameter *rs:Format:*

[image]

And also don't forget to include Omit expression - `=Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive` - this will prevent from passing this additional parameter in interactive mode (html).

Comment: actually i want the same navigation without the reporting server between the excel sheets.

Comment: an amateur question please... in the sub report do I have to define a new parameter with the name rs:format?.. sorry I have never attempted to do such a thing.

Comment: If I understand you correct and your "User_details" report (which is your drill down report) includes some sub report then - no, you shouldn't do this. You need to include this parameter only in action of your parent "Users" report. And also include "Omit expression" there.

Comment: ok I did what you told me but when i click the report field in ssrs which should jump to user_detail report the following error occours: An attempt was made to set the report parameter 'rs:format' that is not defined in this report. Thank you for your patience and listening to my query.

Comment: I seeing only now that you are using SSRS 2008 and not SSRS 2008R2. If yes then variable Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive isn't implemented, in SSRS 2008 there no way to identify which render is uses (HTML, PDF, EXCEL etc.). If you can't upgrade your SQL server then the only way of workaround is to play with "Go To Url" instead of "Go To report" and use there JS. Look this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881387/how-to-pass-multiple-values-to-drilldown-report

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and guidance @roman. I will look into it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I created a report that is similar. What I did was place the sub report into a tablix textbox on the main report. Then right clicked the sub report. In the properties dialog that shows, select visibility. You then want to select hide for "When the report initially run:". Next, check the box in front of "Display can be toggled by this report item:". A dropdown should now enable that allows you to select the field you want to be able to click so the sub report data now shows.

This is in VS 2012 with SQL Server Reporting Services Designers 
Version 11.0.3436.0.